# Penalty for Kolmogorov–Smirnov statistic when using more number of parameters?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, r-squared, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

When I use R square (Coefficient of determination), it can be adjusted according to the number of parameter being examed,

[image]

My question is

1. when I using K-S statistic, is there similar way to account for the extra parameter being used?

[image]

2. What's the general way for adding penalty for other goodness-of fit statistic?

Answer (score 1):

The size of the effect of estimating a parameter depends on the distribution being tested for and on the particular parameter being estimated.

For example,

- Lilliefors test critical values for a normal distribution with one unknown parameter differs for unknown mean vs unknown variance, and
- Lilliefors test critical values for an exponential distribution with unknown scale differs from either of those critical values for a normal (in the cases I looked at it lays between them)

[This is easily verified by simulation.]

Consequently you can't just say "oh, I am estimating $p$ parameters, so scale it by this simple function of $n$ and $p$". It depends on *which* parameters and *which* distributions.